# Set Request Header Using Angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, jwt, authorization

l'm stuck in a very strange problem, I want to send an extra param Authorization in my  request with angular to a service spring boot , just like this

```
Request headers
Authorization: bearer t-3e57cc74-3e7a-4fc7-9bbb-f6c83252db01
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=908D73C50F09E75C9A0D674C4CB33D2F; ROUTEID=.1; __unam=3c3246b-13bc693352d-aa1535c-1
```

But Using this code
**in AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    checkfingeradmin() {


        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ' http://localhost:4200',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': ' POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': ' 3600',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me',
  'Authorization':
           'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJoYXRlbTEyMyIsImF1dGgiOlt7ImF1dGhvcml0eSI6IlJPTEVfRU1Q'
        });
        this.http
            .get<any>(

                'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pointage/ExitAdmin',
                { headers: headers }

            }
            )
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
}
```

and **in Controller Spring boot**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/pointage")
public class PointageController {  @GetMapping ("/EnterAdmin")
     public  ResponseEntity EnterAdmin(){
            return ResponseEntity.ok("for testing");}}
```

and i using this **class jwtTokenFilter** just for get message in may console for check result in my server Spring boot

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter  {
 @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) httpServletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) httpServletResponse;

 String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
      Enumeration<String> e = req.getHeaderNames();
      while(e.hasMoreElements()){
          String param = (String) e.nextElement();
          System.out.print(param + " : " + req.getHeader(param));
          System.out.print("\n");
if(req.getHeader(param).equals("access-control-request-headers")  ){
    System.out.print("\n========================= \n");
    System.out.print(req.getHeader(param));
    System.out.print("\n========================= \n");
}}}
```

> It send like this which is not passing the value, also its request
>   type become OPTION instead of GET, here is console

```
host : localhost:8080
connection : keep-alive
accept : */*
access-control-request-method : GET
access-control-request-headers : authorization
origin : null
sec-fetch-mode : cors
sec-fetch-site : cross-site
user-agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
accept-encoding : gzip, deflate, br
accept-language : fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,und;q=0.6

========================= 
bearerToken : null
 msgaccess-control-allow-credentialsmsg : nullnull
```

Can anyone tell me how can I pass it like this Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJoYXRlbTEyMyIsImF1dGgiOlt7ImF1dGhvcml0eSI6IlJPTEVfRU1Q'

Comment: I thing you need to all the header settings implement in your back-end technology. In front-end like angular you need to pass them.

Comment: have you enable CORS in Spring Security ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Angular code seems to be correct.

You should check your Spring Security configuration. 
In addition to `@CrossOrigin` annotation, CORS should be enabled via `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...
    }
}
```

More details in [Spring official documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)